# MeteorJS Synchronization only on demand, not continously

Tags: cordova, meteor, synchronization

For a project I need a synchronization between app-side databases (iOS, Android, WebApp) and server-side backend.
MeteorJS could be the right choice for me, only the project demands a free configurable synchronization, meaning it should:

- save the data permanently offline
- synchronize only on demand, e.g. once every minute, hour or day

Therefor I may want to use Meteor-Cordova and GroundDB.
My question:

Is it possible to synchronize the meteor databases (minimongo <-> mongo) only on demand and not instantly?

The reason for that is to save bandwidth on dataplan and also serverside.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible by using [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) to return database data as opposed to the usual [pub/sub](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) pattern.  You can still have a [local (sessional) minimongo database](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) on the client side by constructing an anonymous collection, which provides all the benefits of a client-side mongoDB, but rather than updating reactively, you populate/repopulate it as and when you see fit with your method calls.  The only thing to note here is that your methods would need to return [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) - i.e. actual documents as opposed to cursors.

It's also very easy to use [amplify](http://docs.meteor.com/#amplify) to cache the database between sessions and then poll-and-diff when the user reconnects, which would further reduce bandwidth.  I think this functionality is effectively built into the [GroundDB](https://atmospherejs.com/package/grounddb) package, but I've never actually used it, just rolled my own.

Comment: Hi richsilv,
thank you for the fast reply. I cannot overlook it right now, since I haven't gotten my hands on Meteor so far (well, except for the examples).
But it sounds pretty easy and doable from what you are saying.
So I can also pull collections from the server onto my app, then disconnect, update them and reconnect whenever I want?
Since you wrote that I have to construct the collections client side?
The EJSON shouldn't be a problem.
Also, would it be possible to implement the offline storage natively later on, so to not have a 5mb limit, say in Android SQLite or iPhone DBs respectively?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  I don't know about the relevant APIs for those DBs, but I'm sure they exist and could be used in exactly the same way - it's just a case of writing an efficient poll-and-diff in your Meteor code and calling this when required, whether it's just on reconnect or more often (and GroundDB may take care of that for you).

Comment: Just found this, should do the trick regarding cursor -> EJSON:
https://github.com/zol/meteor-famous-leaderboard/blob/master/client/cursor-to-array.js